# Cannot Fix Server Socket Flutter Dart on Visiual Studio

Tags: android, flutter, sockets, dart, serversocket

How can i solve this error? I have loaded localhost but still getting same error. This is my code:

```
Future<void> connect() async {
  var server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 80);

  server.listen((request) async {
    // Check if the path is '/login'
    if (request.uri.path == '/login') {
      // Create OpenId instance with the current request.
      OpenId openId = OpenId(request);

      // Switch the mode
      switch (openId.mode) {
        // No mode is set
        case '':
          {
            //Redirect the user to the authUrl.
            request.response
              ..redirect(openId.authUrl())
              ..close();
            break;
          }
        // Authentication failed/cancelled.
```

Error:

```
E/flutter (16515): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart state.cc(184)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 80
```

Comment: And welcome to Stackoverflow. If possible, you should post you code and error messages as text instead of using screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Lower port numbers like port 80 is usually restricted to only be used by program running as administrator. So the error you have tells you that port 80 is restricted by permissions.

Instead of running the application as administrator you can use a higher port number like 8080.